# How to authonticate only one / offline with client.json key for Gmail API?

Tags: python, email, gmail, gmail-api

I am running an app that needs to access the gmail emails. I had store the credentials in the json file and writing pickle file to cache the token. Is it really necessary to authenticate every time you run the application ? I am running application on Pi and DO NOT HAVE an access to it once i deploy that. How can store the cache that i can use for longer time/ multiple time as right now it is going to expire in the middle of the run and turn off my application.  I followed the Google API docs but hard to follow that. Here is my code for the authentication would look like(it is same as their documentation. You can comment out the Pi library and its function that would not stop you to run the code.)

Could anyone please suggest a better way to do this ?

```py
# GMail Downloader using the GMail API

# Logs into GMail using the API, checks for Iridium SBD messages every minute,
# saves the message and attachment to file, and moves the message out of the inbox

# Follow these instructions to create your credentials:
# https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import base64
import email
import datetime
import time

from apiclient import discovery

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from apiclient import errors

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# Pi libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

Relay_Ch1 = 26
Relay_Ch2 = 20
Relay_Ch3 = 21

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(Relay_Ch1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Relay_Ch2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Relay_Ch3, GPIO.OUT)

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/gmail-python-quickstart.json
#SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly' # Read only
# SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify' # Everything except delete
SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/' # Full permissions
# CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
# APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'

def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    return service

def ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, user_id, query=''):
    """List all Messages of the user's mailbox matching the query.

    Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        query: String used to filter messages returned.
        Eg.- 'from:user@some_domain.com' for Messages from a particular sender.

    Returns:
        List of Messages that match the criteria of the query. Note that the
        returned list contains Message IDs, you must use get with the
        appropriate ID to get the details of a Message.
    """
    response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id,q=query).execute()
    messages = []
    if 'messages' in response:
        messages.extend(response['messages'])

    while 'nextPageToken' in response:
        page_token = response['nextPageToken']
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query,pageToken=page_token).execute()
        messages.extend(response['messages'])

    return messages

def SaveAttachments(service, user_id, msg_id):
    """Get and store attachment from Message with given id.

    Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        msg_id: ID of Message containing attachment.
    """
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id).execute()

    local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(message['internalDate'])/1000.)
    date_str = local_date.strftime("%y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_")

    for part in message['payload']['parts']:
        if part['filename']:
            if 'data' in part['body']:
                data=part['body']['data']
            else:
                att_id=part['body']['attachmentId']
                att=service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId=user_id, messageId=msg_id,id=att_id).execute()
                data=att['data']
            file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data.encode('UTF-8'))
            path = date_str+part['filename']

            with open(path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(file_data)
                f.close()

def SaveMessageBody(service, user_id, msg_id):
    """Save the body from Message with given id.

    Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        msg_id: ID of Message.
    """
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()
    msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
    # mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
    mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)
    messageMainType = mime_msg.get_content_maintype()
    file_data = ''
    #print(messageMainType)
    if messageMainType == 'multipart':
        for part in mime_msg.get_payload():
            partType = part.get_content_maintype()
            #print('...'+partType)
            if partType == 'multipart':
                for multipart in part.get_payload():
                    multipartType = multipart.get_content_maintype()
                    #print('......'+multipartType)
                    if multipartType == 'text':
                        file_data += multipart.get_payload()
                        break # Only get the first text payload
            elif partType == 'text':
                file_data += part.get_payload()
    elif messageMainType == 'text':
        file_data += mime_msg.get_payload()

    local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(message['internalDate'])/1000.)
    date_str = local_date.strftime("%y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_")
    
    subject = GetSubject(service, user_id, msg_id);
    for c in r' []/\;,><&*:%=+@!#^()|?^': # substitute any invalid characters
        subject = subject.replace(c,'_')
 
    path = date_str+subject+".txt"

    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(file_data)
        f.close()

def GetSubject(service, user_id, msg_id):
    """Returns the subject of the message with given id.

    Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        msg_id: ID of Message.
    """
    subject = ''
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id).execute()
    payload = message["payload"]
    headers = payload["headers"]
    for header in headers:
        if header["name"] == "Subject":
            subject = header["value"]
            break
    return subject

def MarkAsRead(service, user_id, msg_id):
    """Marks the message with given id as read.

    Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        msg_id: ID of Message.
    """
    service.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, body={ 'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}).execute()

def MoveToLabel(service, user_id, msg_id, dest):
    """Changes the labels of the message with given id to 'move' it.

    Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        msg_id: ID of Message.
        dest: destination label
    """
    # Find Label_ID of destination label
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId=user_id).execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])
    for label in labels:
        if label['name'] == dest: dest_id = label['id']
    # service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
    service.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, body={ 'addLabelIds': [dest_id]}).execute()
    service.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, body={ 'removeLabelIds': ['INBOX']}).execute()

def main():
    """Creates a Gmail API service object.
    Searches for unread messages with "SBD Msg From Unit" in the subject.
    Saves the message body and attachment to disk.
    Marks the message as read.
    Moves it to the SBD folder.
    """
    # credentials = get_credentials()
    # http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    # service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()
    # results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me, q="subject:"SBD Msg From Unit" is:unread has:attachment").execute()
    # messages = results.get('messages', [])

    messages = ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, 'me', 'subject:\"Emergency Alert Activated: GSATMicro\" is:unread')  # has:attachment
    if messages:
        for message in messages:
            print('Processing: '+GetSubject(service, 'me', message["id"]))
            SaveMessageBody(service, 'me', message["id"])
            # SaveAttachments(service, 'me', message["id"])
            MarkAsRead(service, 'me', message["id"])
            # MoveToLabel(service, 'me', message["id"], 'SBD')
            #email_subject = message['subject']
            #email_from = message['from']
            #if email_from == "alerts@gsattrack.com" and email_subject == 'EMERGENCY: GSATMicro - Emergency On':
            print("Emergency Alert received from GSATMicro..")
            print("\n Help will be on its way .. Turning relay ON.. \n")
            #Control the Channel 1
            print("\n Turning Relay 1 ON.. \n")
            GPIO.output(Relay_Ch1, GPIO.HIGH)
            print("Channel 1:The Common Contact is access to the Normal Open Contact!")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(Relay_Ch1, GPIO.LOW)
            print("Channel 1:The Common Contact is access to the Normal Closed Contact!\n")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(Relay_Ch1, GPIO.HIGH)
    #else:
        #print('No messages found!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('GMail API Downloader')
    print('Press Ctrl-C to quit')
    try:
        while True:
            #print('Checking for messages...')
            main()
            for i in range(60):
                time.sleep(1) # Sleep
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Ctrl-C received!')
```

Comment: `I am running application on Pi and DO NOT HAVE an access to it once i deploy that.` What is Pi? And what you don't have access to? The token.json file? Can you provide more details about the context in which this is being executed?

Comment: Sorry its Raspberry Pi. We have a satellite device which sends a email to account which some sensor data. If one of our sensor data is high we are operating a relay to turn on the system and cool something down. Raspberry Pi is located remotely so once we start the screipt it just polls the email account every minute to see if there any new emails in the inbox, if yes process it. Is there any way we can catch the token for longer than usual such as we only save it in the device very first time when we run the system ?

Comment: If you are able to store and retrieve the `token.json` you shouldn't need to grant authorization every time (the refresh token would take care of it). Are you noticing that it expires? Also, you could use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) to avoid all user interaction, would this be feasible for you?